# How to custom url in phpartisan serve

Tags: laravel

I use mac High Sierra I want to change url from
 `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` to `test.dev`

when I run `phpartisan serve`

How can I do something like this,

I'm using `Laravel & MAMP`

Comment: Laravel valet: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/valet or you want to create a Virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MAMP, you do not need to use

> php artisan serve

Just put inside your html/www root and create virtual host.